# Fading into scenes in unity does not work correctly

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, scene, fading

When I fade out of a scene in unity and try to fade back into the original screen, I am met with a black screen. For example, going back to the main menu from the pause screen leaves me with a black screen and I believe it is a problem with my code. How should I fix this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Fading : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Texture2D fadeOutTexture;
    public float fadeSpeed = 0.8f;

    private int drawDepth = -1000;
    private float alpha = 1.0f;
    private int fadeDir = -1;

    void  OnGUI()
    {
        alpha += fadeDir * fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        alpha = Mathf.Clamp01(alpha);

        GUI.color = new Color(GUI.color.r, GUI.color.g, GUI.color.b, alpha);
        GUI.depth = drawDepth;
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), fadeOutTexture);
    }

    public float BeginFade (int direction)
    {
        fadeDir = direction;
        return (fadeSpeed);
    }

    void OnLevelWasLoaded()
    {
        alpha = 1;
        BeginFade(-1);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Try asking on http://answers.unity3d.com/ you'll most likely get an answer there

Comment: You really should NOT be using the ancient legacy gui system.  Use only the ordinary Unity.UI now. It's just not going to be practical using legacy systems.

Comment: As kentor mentions there are literally ~100 full working examples of this easily googleable http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/780323/unity-ui-fading-canvaspanel.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because trivial to google solution.

Comment: Stack overflow format is to NOT close this type of question.  It has specific code with a bug.  The existence of other solutions does not negate the validity of this question.

Answer (score 2):

Your code says:

1. When game starts, immediately start fading.
2. OnGUI (called anywhere from 30 to 100 times per second): fade out
3. If you call the method BeginFade ... do nothing (you are already fading)
4. Carry on fading to black forever.

There is never a piece of code to STOP fading.

You could add a bool "isFading" and put all the OnGUI code in:

```
if( isFading )
{
 ...
}
```

...but you'll still need to STOP at some point. e.g. the last line of OnGUI could be:

```
if( isFading && alpha <= 0 )
   isFading = false;
```

Comment: I would then have to reset the alpha to 1 then right?

Comment: I'm apologize for my lack of understanding but I am still greeted by the the same black screen.

Comment: Yes. Normally you have two methods - a "start fad to black" and a "start fade to normal". And you have a boolean to say "am I currently fading" AND a "which direction am I going - positve or negative". You have all these bits, but in different places, and/or only half implemented. If you write down your algorithm on paper, not in code, and think about what you've written, it'll work fine.

Comment: I'm guessing that the best solution is to reset the process every time a new scene is loaded. Is that a good idea, and how should I do that.

Comment: That should be a separate question, but briefly: there are methods Unity provides on MonoBehaviour that you can implement to get notificed whenever the scene is started. Look at Awake and Start especially

Answer (score 1):

Brackeys has a simple and effective way to fade in and out between scenes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HwZQt94uHQ

Comment: This link is only good for as long as it's available. Including the relevant information directly in your answer ensures it's available as long as this question is here. Link-only answers should be converted to a comment on the question.

Comment: Yes, but my change level function isn't compatible with the video